# Improving performance when loading data in current Map using ArcGIS Pro SDK and C#

Tags: c#, performance, layer-file, arcgis-pro-sdk

I want to load data into a current map in ArcGIS Pro 2.9. For this purpose, I want to use a `.lyrx` file. Currently, I have implemented it with:

```cs
Uri uriLayerPath = new Uri(strLayerPath);
LayerFactory.Instance.CreateFeatureLayer(uriLayerPath, map, LayerPosition.AddToBottom);
```

It works well in principle, but the performance is very poor compared to the `Add Data` dialog in ArcGIS Pro.

How can I improve the performance?